# Flutter BLoC keep rebuilding CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

My CircularProgressIndicator gets rebuilt 2-3 times and it makes the spinning animation restart everytime even though the state is not emitted multiple times.

my BlocBuilder:

```
BlocBuilder<DayDetailedCubit, DayDetailedState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is Loading) {
                  print("loading");
                  // return LoadingIndicator();
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else if (state is Loaded) {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: CustomPaddings.tabListSpacing * 0.6,
                        ),
                        MoodSection(moodEntries: state.dayDetailed.moodEntries),
                        StressSection(stressEntries: state.dayDetailed.stressEntries,),
                        SectionAchievement(achievementEntries: state.dayDetailed.achievementEntries,),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: CustomPaddings.tabListSpacing,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (state is Initial) {
                  return Text("initial");
                } else if (state is Error) {
                  return Text("error");
                }
                return Text("unknown");
              },
            ),
```

I'm emitting the Loading state from my Cubit:

```
Future<void> getDayDetailed(Timestamp timestamp) async {
emit(Loading());
print("cubit: get day detailed");
final failureOrDayDetailed = await getDayDetailedEntries(timestamp);
failureOrDayDetailed.fold(
    (l) {
      print("error");
      emit(Error());
    }, (dayDetailed) => emit(Loaded(dayDetailed)));
```

}

and finally the getDayDetailed is called ONLY from an init state here:

```
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  BlocProvider.of<DayDetailedCubit>(context).getDayDetailed(widget.timestamp);
  }
```

As I know the Bloc won't rebuild if the content is not different even if the state is emitted multiple times so I'm not sure why my CircularProgressIndicator is being rebuilt few times.

Comment: From what you provided here, it should work fine. The only problem I could think of is that your initState() is called several times, as a result the `getDayDetailed()` method is called several times as well and you emit the `Loading()` state multiple times, too.

Comment: Aw, thanks for your feedback , I will put a log tomorrow to see if indeed it happens like that. Thank you

Comment: You can also add a `Key` to your loading indicator to prevent creating new instances of the same widget. This should help with rebuilds